# set intersection

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want to calculate the gcd of two numbers m and n by prime factorization and taking common factors
like this. Take example m = 36 n = 48

```
vector<int> factors1 = prime_factorization(m); // 2 2 3 3 
vector<int> factors2 = prime_factorization(n); // 2 2 2 2 3
vector<int> intersection(10);
set_intersection(factors1.begin(), factors1.end(), factors2.begin(), factors2.end(), intersection.begin());
```

intersection is now  2 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. For this i must set the size of the vector beforehand. Also the remaining elements are set to 0. I don't want this to happen.

Is there a better way to do this? Using sets or anything else?

Also, how do i calculate the product of elements in the vector intersection (2*2*3) using stl ignoring the zeroes?

Comment: Are you set on doing it this way? Because euclid's GCD algorithm  is much better for this.

Comment: @Null set      i know euclid's, but just wanted to compute gcd in different ways

Comment: It's better when the factors are represented as prime ** power. Also, after a decomposition prime factors will be sorted, so the intrsection will be much easier to compute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [back-inserter](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/):

```
vector<int> intersection;
set_intersection(..., back_inserter(intersection));
```

Note that there are much better ways of determining the GCD, such as [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 5):

Oli's answer is best in the situation as you describe it.  But if you were using a vector that already existed and had elements that you were writing over, and you wanted to chop off the extra numbers, you can do it a different way.  By calling the vector member [`erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) using the return value of set_intersection:

```
intersection.erase(
    set_intersection(factors1.begin(), factors1.end(), factors2.begin(), factors2.end(), intersection.begin()),
    intersection.end());
```